# Android Toolbar not showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, toolbar

currently I am using Android's new toolbar (in appcompat). It works fine until I try the following method: `toolbar.bringToFront()`. When I call this, the toolbar disappears. My layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarThemePopup"
    />


<com.asdev.sechat.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Now the reason I need it in front is that the `SlidingTabLayout` has a shadow which covers the toolbar, and I don't want that. Anyone know how I can bring the toolbar to the top and still have it visible? Thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up, in your ViewPager element, you are using the deprecated `fill_parent` attribute where you should be using `match_parent`. This isn't going to solve your problem, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: OK thanks can't hurt I guess

Comment: But man I should read more documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs:

> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with the new child ordering.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()

It makes sense that this would mess up your layout. you may have to look into a relative layout or find a different way to get rid of the shadow. or if you're min sdk 21 you could probably set the elevation on the toolbar manually.

relativelayout example:

```
<RelativeLayout         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.asdev.sechat.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:align_parentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarThemePopup"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you're saying I have to create another relative view and put the toolbar on top of that?

Comment: something like the layout i just posted. you want the toolbar on the bottom so it draws on top if that makes sense

Comment: OK I see. I thought the top element would be rendered on top. Guess not. I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: it draws in order from top to bottom. always. also you should use ?android:attr/actionBarSize for the height instead of 56 dp.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Use `bringToFront` in your java file for toolbar will solve your problem.</del>

**Edit**

This is working solution in my app

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />

    <com.asdev.sechat.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/tab_height"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Like is said in my question, this makes the toolbar invisible.

Comment: Have you tried minHeight=56 and height=wrap_content for toolbar, if yes than use these for SlidingTabLayout

Comment: Why for the sliding layout? I'm sure its smaller than 56dp

Comment: i have update my answer, this solution works for me, i took this code from my working project.